# PHP cURl: Can I check if my user agent is working?

Tags: php, curl

I'm writing a cURL script, but how can I check if it's working and passing properly when it's visiting the website?

```
 $ckfile = '/tmp/cookies.txt';
    $useragent= "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7A400";


    $ch = curl_init ("http://website.com");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER , true); 
          => true
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); // set user agent
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just make a php page like this on your server and try your script on your own url

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

and check the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` string.

You can also achieve the same things by looking at the `Apache` logs.

But I am pretty sure curl is setting the `User-Agent` string like it should ;-)

Comment: Thanks Rage! Is tehre a way for me to contact you privately rage?

Comment: @Doug: for? --------------------------

Comment: Wanted to ask you more about cURL, but it's okay if you don't want to.

Comment: @Doug: not really I don't want to just I think SO users are more available then me ^^ and would provide as much answers as have (or even more) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the FF extension LiveHTTPHEaders will help you see exactly what happens to the headers when using a normal browsing session.

http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/

This will increase your understanding of how your target server responds, and even shows if it redirects your request internally.

Comment: However, this won't check that the UA he's set in his PHP code is valid... at all...

Comment: Yes but by looking at a working example of a UA you at least know 1 that works and can therefore eliminate that variable, then another then another ...